# CSS Grid Elements Overlapping When Resized

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm in the early stages of creating this WYSIWYG Editor using CSS grid and I have a section for the actual document with the ID `#doc-space` and a sidebar where all the formatting tools sit and for some reason when the screen gets too small the doc-space overlaps the sidebar (even though that's the main thing CSS grid is meant to prevent).

So here is a preview of my code:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/REpmgz

And you will see, when resizing the preview window, the overlap of the doc-space over the sidebar.

Supposedly when the doc-space has a `grid-column` value of `5 / 25` and the sidebar a value of `1 / 5` there should be no overlap. So maybe I'm missing a certain property?

Comment: Interesting problem.. I haven't figured it out yet, but something seems to happen if you replace #doc-space style grid-column: 8 / 25 with 3 / 25. I don't really understand why the top bar is respecting the column size though.

Comment: you have added a min-width which is the culprit

Comment: try to remove this from top div class="grid-item" id="sidebar" and place it last

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website / demo doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).